# root account locked GCP VM instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, instance

I have been locked outside from the GCP VM Instance. When I connect with ssh ,I get :
`ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255]`.

When I connect with serial console :

```
You are in emerg
Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked.
See sulogin(8) man page for more details.
```

I have already mount the disk to another VM instance. 
Have you any idea of what should I change to make it accessible again?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/8/sulogin

Comment: Should I create a inittab and write sulogin inside?

Comment: Question, why would your root account be accessible?

Comment: @Stap7 how are you connecting to the instance? and why root?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to loggin with a [different user](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh#try_a_new_user) or use your disk in a [different instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh#use_your_disk_on_a_new_instance)